# Padding and margin not working on breakpoints

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwindCSS. At the moment i want to make two buttons. They should be small (with a small vertical padding) on desktop screens and big (with a bigger vertical padding) on mobile screens. I added the tailwindCSS property py-4 for smaller screens and md:py-2 for bigger screens. For some reason it doesn't work. For test purposes I also changed the background color of the button in my code. The background color switch works just fine, but the padding remains the same.

**Code**

```
 <div class="flex justify-between flex-col md:flex-row items-center mt-4 md:mt-4">
            <div>
                <button @click.prevent="showInviteInputs" v-if="community.active == 1" class="px-3 w-full md:w-auto py-4 md:py-0 bg-green-600 text-white font-bold rounded hover:bg-green-700">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-plus "></i>
                    Freunde einladen
                </button>
                <button v-if="community.active == 1" @click.prevent="showModalcloseGroup = true" class="px-3 w-full md:w-auto py-4 md:py-0  mt-4 bg-gray-200 md:bg-yellow-200 text-gray-700 font-bold rounded hover:bg-gray-300">Gruppe schließen</button>
            </div>
            <div class="flex items-center">
                <h1 class="text-gray-700 mt-4 md:mt-0 font-bold">Host: {{community.host}} (Ich)</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
    colors: {
      transparent: 'transparent',
      current: 'currentColor',
      black: colors.black,
      blue:colors.blue,
      white: colors.white,
      gray: colors.trueGray,
      indigo: colors.indigo,
      green: colors.green,
      red: colors.rose,
      yellow: colors.amber,
      ccblue: {
        DEFAULT: '#1A2238',
      },
      cclavendel: {
        DEFAULT: '#9DAAF2',
      }, 
      ccorange: {
        DEFAULT: '#FF6A3D',
      },
       ccyellow: {
        DEFAULT: '#F4DB7D',
      },
    }
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**On bigger devices:**

[image: On the desktop version]

**And on smaller devices:**

[image: small-device]

Comment: Could you please post your code as a text snippet rather than an image? Makes it easier for people to provide help.

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry :')

Comment: If I run your code through [play.tailwindcss.com](https://play.tailwindcss.com/) it seems to work as desired. I can see the vertical padding within the buttons changing between screen sizes. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you please tell how you are using tailwind css? It should be working because I too tried in https://play.tailwindcss.com/ an d it's working. I think you might not have properly build the css file.

Comment: I'm using tailwindcss as a npm package. I followed the installation instructions in the documentation to install tailwind in my laravel-project.

Comment: @pkoehler Can you add your `tailwind.config.js` file to the question as well?

Comment: Sure, I still haven't got it fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="flex justify-between flex-col md:flex-row items-center mt-4 md:mt-4">
        <div>
            <button @click.prevent="showInviteInputs" v-if="community.active == 1" class="px-3 w-full md:w-auto py-4 md:py-2 bg-green-600 text-white font-bold rounded hover:bg-green-700">
                <i class="fas fa-user-plus "></i>
                Freunde einladen
            </button>
            <button v-if="community.active == 1" @click.prevent="showModalcloseGroup = true" class="px-3 w-full md:w-auto py-4 md:py-2  mt-4 bg-gray-200 md:bg-yellow-200 text-gray-700 font-bold rounded hover:bg-gray-300">Gruppe schließen</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex items-center">
            <h1 class="text-gray-700 mt-4 md:mt-0 font-bold">Host: {{community.host}} (Ich)</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

You give `md:py-0` instade of `md:py-2`.